# SubSonic equivalent of an SQL update

Tags: subsonic, subsonic2.2

I'm wondering if the following SQL update query is possible using the equivalent SubSonic commands:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYFIELD = MYFIELD + 3 WHERE ANOTHERFIELD = ANOTHERVALUE
```

I couldn't find a suitable way to make a reference to the same field with the Setting object.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Fernando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute this query using **QueryCommand** object of subsonic.

You can find similar samples over here [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20071012093828/http://www.dennydotnet.com/post/SubSonic-QueryCommand-Object.aspx) and [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20070701204358/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/scottkuhl/archive/2006/12/06/100537.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think I can get it done by using the samples on the first link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can use "UpdateExpression" - it's a string value that you pass in with the "simple" query tool. I don't have the code or the sample in front of me - it might be "SetExpression" but it allows you to update using a string like you've entered here.

Comment: I'm going to take a look at it, see if I can make it work that way, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did a test using what you said on SetExpression() but somehow I'm not convinced I'm using it right.... it works but it feels (and looks) kinda funny you know?

```
int count = new Update(MyTable.Schema).SetExpression("MyField").EqualTo("MyField + 20")
.Where(....)
```

As I said, the update worked but I'm not sure if that's the intended way of doing it, and if it is (or even if it isn't), then how could I use a parameter instead of hard-coding the value in the expression.